# Identify mouse events during requestPointerLock

Tags: javascript, jquery, pointerlock

Is there any way to identify right click event ("contextmenu") & scroll events while pointer lock API is enabled? I am trying to create a browser-based 3d game in which the player will be able to perform different activities by left clicking, right clicking, middle clicking and scrolling - while pointer is locked.

**index.html**

```
<body><button id="lock">Start game</button</body>
```

**app.js**

```
$("#lock").on("click", function(e) {
  lockPointer(); // invokes the requestPointerLock API
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// this works perfectly
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
  // do stuff on left click
});

// this does not work
$("body").on("contextmenu", function(e) {
  // do stuff on right click
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For right click you can use `mousedown` or `mouseup` event, it works with `requestPointerLock`

```
$('body').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 1) {
        // left button
    } else if (e.which === 2) {
        // middle button
    } else if (e.which === 3) {
        // right button
    }
});
```

For scrolling you can use `wheel` event:

```
$('body').on('wheel', function(e) {
    var dx = e.originalEvent.deltaX;
    var dy = e.originalEvent.deltaY;

    if (dy < 0) {
        // scroll up
    } else if (dy > 0) {
        // scroll down
    }

    if (dx < 0) {
        // scroll left (some mice support this)
    } else if (dx > 0) {
        // scroll right (some mice support this)
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to suffice my requirements. Thanks a lot! :-)